# How do I hide field in node.tpl.php?

Tags: entities

I would like to hide this field if it is empty. No clue where to start with my limited PHP/Drupal knowledge. The Else would be "Nothing to see here."

```
<?php 

  $my_field_value = $content['product:field_course_no_']['#object']->field_pd_number['und'][0]['safe_value'];


echo "<input type=\"button\" value=\"Danh's Cart\" id=\"Adding PDC course\" onclick=\"setCookie('class','$my_field_value" . "r_000000000000');document.cartform.submit();\" style=\"float:none;\" /><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"id\" value=\"$my_field_value\" />";
```

?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
    if(isset($content['product:field_course_no_']['#object']->field_pd_number['und'][0]['safe_value'])){ 
     $my_field_value =  $content['product:field_course_no_']['#object']->field_pd_number['und'][0]['safe_value'];
} else {
        $my_field_value = '';
}
```

Comment: What about if someone puts a space in the field and nothing else? [This article](http://techtalk.virendrachandak.com/php-isset-vs-empty-vs-is_null/) makes a case for using !empty instead of isset in that case.

Comment: I think in that case I would validate the output of the field once it was determined the field was set with a value or not. Once the string or integer is stored into a variable it's easier to sanitize or manipulate the data in the way you're suggesting. Unfortunately I don't think you can check for field variables on the node using !empty. OP probably already tried that and that's what brought him here to ask.